# How to make ranges in a big dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, range

I want to go through a folder and want to check to which timezone each file in the folder belong to. To that I have a csv file

```
ip1         ip2           timezone
0           16777215          0
16777216    16777471       +10:00
16777472    16778239       +08:00
16778240    16779263       +11:00
16779264    16781311       +08:00
16781312    16785407       +09:00
...
```

When the particular ip_number is between ip1 and ip2, the correlated timezone is in the third column.

```
df = pd.read_csv('IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB11.csv', parse_dates=True)

path="Testordner"
os.chdir(path)
result = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format("csv"))]
os.chdir("..")
for i in result:
    df2 = pd.read_csv("twiceaweek/"+i, parse_dates=True)
    w1,x1,y1,z1=i.split('.')
    w=int(w1)
    x=int(x1)
    y=int(y1)
    ip_number= 16777216*w + 65536*x + 256*y+1
```

I have no idea how to range the numbers between `ip1` and `ip2` and how to merge the ip_number of each file to them and get my timezone. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What is `result`? Do you want to achieve? Please edit for clarification. Otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Just edited my post. I want to achieve that I find the right timezone for my ip_number and for that I have find in which range between ip1 and ip2 my ip_number is

Comment: Are the numbers in `ip1` always larger than those (shifted) in `ip2` by `1`?

Comment: Yes, the first row is valid for all ip_number between 0 and 16777215, the second from 16777216 to 16777471 and so on ..

Comment: `df.loc[(df['ip1'] <= ip_number) & (ip_number <= df['ip2']), 'timezone']`?

Answer (score 0):

You want `qcut`:

```
thresholds = list(df['ip1']) + [df['ip2'].iloc[-1]]

# test:
ips = df[['ip1', 'ip2']].mean(axis=1).astype(int)

# bucketing
buckets = pd.cut(ips, thresholds,
                 right=True, 
                 include_lowest=True,
                 labels=False)

# get the labels:
df['timezone'].values[buckets]
```

Output:

```
array(['0', '+10:00', '+08:00', '+11:00', '+08:00', '+09:00'],
  dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `merge_asof`. It allows to find the last index less than the search value, which is what you need. So to find the timezone when you have found the ip number, use:

```
tmp = pd.merge_asof(pd.DataFrame([ip_number], columns=['ip']), df, left_on=['ip'],
      right_on=['ip1'])
tmp = tmp[tmp.ip2>ip_number]
if len(tmp) > 0:
    tz = tmp.at[0, 'timezone']
else:
    tz = ''       # not found
```

Alternatively, you can use `searchsorted`:

```
ix = df['ip2'].searchsorted([ip_number], 'right')[0]
if ix == len(df) or df.at[ix, 'ip1']>ip_number:
    tz = ''        # not found:
else:
    tz = df.at[ix, 'timezone']
```